# How to stop firing onbeforeunload function on RadGrid Postbacks in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, dom-events, radgrid, onbeforeunload

Scenario: I have `onbeforeunload` function on .aspx page which I am using to display a message before navigating away from current page (ASP.NET Application). This page is quite complex where post backs are happening at quite a few times e.g. I have multiple buttons, Rad Grid, Rad Window PopUps etc.

So, all the buttons call `onbeforeunload` whenever they are clicked and message box is being called un-necessarily. To prevent `onbeforeunload` message displaying I am just calling another `cancelEvent` function on button's `OnClientClick` event where I am just calling null. By doing this all the button post backs are handled but the RadGrid which I am using has Button Columns (Delete) and whenever a row is deleted from the grid it offcourse refreshes the grid which ultimately calls `onbeforeunload`.

Could please anyone tell me how I can prevent `onbeforeunload` when I delete anything from RadGrid.  Following is the code snippet that I am using and working fine for buttons but I need help for grid delete column may be some event like Button's `OnClientClick` event that I can use to call my `cancelEvent`.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
            window.event.returnValue = 'If you navigate away from this page any unsaved changes will be lost!';
}

function cancelEvent(event) {
            window[event] = function () {null}
}

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="ActionButtons"
            ValidationGroup="vsDataEntry" OnClientClick="return cancelEvent('onbeforeunload')"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing something like the below

```
<div onclick="return cancelEvent('onbeforeunload')">
    <telerik:RadGrid runat="server">
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

When the click event is triggered it is bubbled through all the element in DOM. We are wrapping the Radgrid inside a div and whenever any click happens inside that div we are removing the onbeforeunload.

Comment: @user1273701 I have also added explanation on why this works.

Comment: +1 neat trick, any idea of how well supported accross browsers?

Comment: @eglasius It has worked for me on latest versions of Chrome, firefox, IE in windows.