# How to stop firing onbeforeunload when a time from RadTimePicker is selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, dom-events, onbeforeunload

Could please anyone tell me how I can stop firing `onbeforeunload` when I select time from `RadTimePicker`. In my scenario I have a `RadTimePicker` and on time selection I am setting a value in `RadComboBox`. I have `cancelEvent(onbeforeunload)` Jquery function on my .aspx page which I am calling on Buttons (`OnClientClick`) and it is working fine also I have `RadGrid` which I have wrapped in a div and calling the same `cancelEvent` JQuery function on its `onclick` event which is also working fine but I can't make it work for `RadTimePicker` time selection. Couple of days ago I posted the similar post when I had a problem with `RadGrid` (can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801334/how-to-stop-firing-onbeforeunload-function-on-radgrid-postbacks-in-asp-net)) and helped by Ramesh and now I am stuck with time selection postback issue.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue by placing the div (which has my RadTimePicker, RadComboBox and some other text fields) inside asp:UpdatePanel. What was heppening, RadTimePicker was doing a Page post back and now by placing UpdatePanel it only updates the panel not the whole page.